# How to create database within a database(postgres)?

Tags: database, postgresql, data-structures, database-design

Actually I'm noob and stuck on this problem for a week. I will try explaining it.
I have table for USER, 
and a table for product
I want to store data of every user for every product. Like if_product_bought, num_of_items, and all.

So only solution I can think of database within database , that is create a copy of products inside user named database and start storing.

If this is possible how or is there any other better solution
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually *don't* create a `database` within a `database` (or a `table` within a `table`) when you use PostgreSQL or any other SQL RDBMS.

You use `tables`, and `JOIN` them. You normally would have an `orders` table, together with an `items_x_orders` table, on top of your `users` and `items`.

This is a very simplified scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    user_id INTEGER /* SERIAL */ NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name text
) ;

CREATE TABLE items
(
    item_id INTEGER /* SERIAL */ NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    item_description text NOT NULL,
    item_unit text NOT NULL,
    item_standard_price decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
) ;

CREATE TABLE orders
(
    order_id INTEGER /* SERIAL */ NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(user_id),
    order_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    other_data TEXT
) ;

CREATE TABLE items_x_orders
(
    order_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES orders(order_id),
    item_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES items(item_id),

    -- You're supposed not to have the item more than once in an order
    -- This makes the following the "natural key" for this table
    PRIMARY KEY (order_id, item_id),

    item_quantity DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL CHECK(item_quantity <> /* > */  0),
    item_percent_discount DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    other_data TEXT
) ;
```

This is all based in the so-called [**Relational Model**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model). What you were thinking about is something else called a [**Hierarchical model**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_database_model), or a  [**document model**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) used in some NoSQL databases (where you store your data as a JSON or XML hierarchical structure).

You would fill those tables with data like:

```
INSERT INTO users
   (user_id, user_name)
VALUES
   (1, 'Alice Cooper') ;

INSERT INTO items
   (item_id, item_description, item_unit, item_standard_price)
VALUES
   (1, 'Oranges', 'kg',  0.75),
   (2, 'Cookies', 'box', 1.25),
   (3, 'Milk',    '1l carton', 0.90) ;

INSERT INTO orders
   (order_id, user_id)
VALUES
   (100, 1) ;

INSERT INTO items_x_orders
   (order_id, item_id, item_quantity, item_percent_discount, other_data)
VALUES
   (100, 1, 2.5, 0.00, NULL),
   (100, 2, 3.0, 0.00, 'I don''t want Oreo'),
   (100, 3, 1.0, 0.05, 'Make it promo milk') ;
```

And then you would produce queries like the following one, where you [`JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) all relevant tables:

```
SELECT
    user_name, item_description, item_quantity, item_unit, 
    item_standard_price, item_percent_discount, 
    CAST(item_quantity * (item_standard_price * (1-item_percent_discount/100.0)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS items_price
FROM
    items_x_orders
    JOIN orders USING (order_id)
    JOIN items USING (item_id)
    JOIN users USING (user_id) ;
```

...and get these results:

```
user_name    | item_description | item_quantity | item_unit | item_standard_price | item_percent_discount | items_price
:----------- | :--------------- | ------------: | :-------- | ------------------: | --------------------: | ----------:
Alice Cooper | Oranges          |          2.50 | kg        |                0.75 |                  0.00 |        1.88
Alice Cooper | Cookies          |          3.00 | box       |                1.25 |                  0.00 |        3.75
Alice Cooper | Milk             |          1.00 | 1l carton |                0.90 |                  5.00 |        0.86
```

You can get all the code and test at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3fedeb73ecda8244ab82e78ea2aedc31)*